# During a validation, how do I determine the name of the control calling the validation?

Tags: vb.net, focus, controls, validating

In vb.net, during a validation, how do I determine the name of the control calling the validation?  The ActiveControl command returns the name of the NEXT control getting the focus, not the control being validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're handling the `Validating` or `Validated` event?  Those events always provide the object that triggered them so you simply have to do :

```
Private Sub DoValidating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) _
                                                  Handles SomeControl.Validating
    Dim controlName As String = DirectCast(sender, Control).Name
    ' etc...
End Sub
```

The standard event handlers always return untyped objects as the `sender` parameter.  When you do `DirectCast(sender, Control)` you're making an assumption that the event was raised by a `Control` type object - could be anything - text box, button, slider, label, whatever.  To get the name of the control you don't have to be more specific since *all* `Control`s will have a `.Name` property.  You have to cast the object since basic objects do *not* have a `.Name` property.  To be safer you can check to be sure that the `sender` is in fact a `Control` like :

```
If TypeOf sender Is Control Then
    Dim controlName As String = DirectCast(sender, Control).Name
        ' etc...
End If
```

After you've cast the object you can access any of the properties of the type you've cast it to.  `DirectCast(sender,Control).Name` is the same as saying `myTextBox1.Name`.

Now, to answer the second question, the above approach is handy when you want one event handler to handle events generated by multiple types of controls which all share a common base property that you are interested in examining.  The base `Control` type, in this case, also has a `.Text` property, but you'll notice that the `TextBox` type overrides the functionality of the `.Text` property so, while you could simply do `DirectCast(sender, Control).Text`, it is better to cast to the correct type.  In this way you would simply do :

```
If TypeOf sender Is TextBox Then
    Dim textBoxText As String = DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text
    ' etc...
End If
```

This allows you to build generic handlers for a variety of events, but also allows you to take specific actions based on the type of the object that generated the event.  Say, for example, you want to perform some common validation tasks for radio buttons, textboxes, comboboxes, etc; but that you also want to do some validation specific to each type you can check the type of the sending object (as above) and then work with it after casting it to its proper type.  If you're doing multiple things with the object you can also save repeated work by setting the cast to a local variable :

```
If TypeOf sender Is TextBox Then
    Dim senderTxtBox As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    Dim senderTxt As String = senderTxtBox.Text
    Dim controlName As String = senderTxtBox.Name
    senderTxtBox.ForeColor = Color.Blue
    ' etc...
End If
```

Not sure if that clears things up?  I'm guessing you wanted the name of the textbox so that you could reference it in code - what is key to observe here is that you don't need to know the name of the object to work with it.  The name is just a string property that is used by the compiler to translate your code.  The name is just a means of obtaining a reference to the actual underlying object.  In the case of an event handler, the object reference is handed to you via the `sender` property, so you don't need to know its name to work with it.

Comment: J...That gives me exactly what I asked for, the control name.  Now how do I get the text value of this control, assuming the control is a text box. I tried: somestring = sender.text, somestring = sender.name.text, some string = controlName.text.

Comment: @SteveZ added some more info for you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks J...,
Correct me if I am wrong, but the trick to being able to reference the "sender" object as a control appears to be to convert the variable from a System.Object to a Control object, which is what the third line accomplishes. Dim ctl As Control = sender

```
Private Sub PhoneValidation(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)     Handles PhoneHomeTextBox.Validating, PhoneMobileTextBox.Validating, PhoneWorkTextBox.Validating

    'This routine strips away all non-numeric characters, and then reformats the remaining 10 digits in standard phone# format.  It rejects any non-null input which does not distill down to exactly 10 or 11 digits

    Dim ctl As Control = sender

    If ctl.Text = "" Then Exit Sub

    Dim x As String = ""
    Dim y As String = ""
    Dim z As String = "0123456789"

    For i = 0 To Len(ctl.Text) - 1
        x = ctl.Text.Substring(i, 1)
        If z.IndexOf(x) > -1 Then  'test each character to extract the numbers
            y = y & x
        End If
    Next

    ...
```